# Python-PPTX: Why does the row height in a table expand if any of the cells in the row have empty text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-pptx

I recently wasted a lot of time trying to fix the row height in one of my Py-PPTX generated tables. The margin-top and margin-height parameters given were '0'. I also tried to control the height using the row.height parameter of the table. But the row was stuck at a larger height.

Accidentally I discovered, this was happening because a few of the cells in my row were empty. As soon as I added some text to the cells, the row height resized to the desired values.

I'm unable to understand why this could be happening, as in, why can't my row show up with the given height and margins without any text in them. I'd appreciate it, if anyone here understands this and could elaborate on it.

[ At the moment, I'm having to fill a space instead of empty text in the table cells. This seems very hacky. ]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I may have an answer.

The empty cells may have a default text styling applied to them with a large point size. PowerPoint will often make default table text 17.8pt when inserting tables manually.

Without your code, it's difficult to know for sure, but if you're applying text styles to the table cell by cell, and it skips blank cells, it may be inheriting the default styling.